# A UK based hosting company that is like HostGator for its web host packages

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, hostgator

This question is unique in the sense of its requirements.

I require a web host like Hostgator that offers the same level of features but is based and hosted in the UK.

This is required due to both UK and EU law relating to location of customer data, so I would appreciate unlike the other threads people don't attack suggest HostGator is fine because it is great but the law is the law.

Comment: We only have one question about how to find hosting.   In general, recommendations questions don't work well here.